# test over 3rd dimension MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a 3d array.    1st dim  is xcoordinate of pixel

2nd dimension is y - coordinate of pixel. 
 3rd coordinate is time (or could be though of as the frame number).

I want to do a test to see if any  pixel is equal to zero for **every single frame** (along 3rd dimension).

How would I write this test?

I need returned the pixels which are ALWAYS true!!!

Comment: i know this might involve the ALL function but i'm not sure exactly on the implementation

Comment: this should be trivial for someone who knows how to code, unfortunately i am very inexperienced, I appreciate your time

Comment: i am seeing some crappy solutions such as testing vs the i+1 frame and then throwing that in a loop... but there has got to be an easier way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than `all` you could use `any`. If I understand you correctly, the code would go something like this for a single "pixel"

```
any(A(x,y,:))
```

where `A` is the 3d matrix. If the result is `1`, then the given pixel does have a non-zero value for at least one frame, and `0` otherwise.

Comment: i got it to work using all(X,dim) specifying dim as time, this solution is good though, even though i found the answer before anyone replied... (i was kinda overlooking something obvious)

Comment: According to how I understood your question, you want to "test to see if any pixel is equal to zero for every single frame ". `all(X,dim)` would return 2d matrix in which, for a given pixel, there `0` if pixel has *at least one* zero. To get a matrix with `0` for all pixels zeroed in *every* frame, you should use `any(X,dim)`. Please correct me if i misunderstood you.

Comment: you are correct, the thing is that for my purposes, it was really irrelivant whether it was true or false, i was just interested in capturing data across the time-dimension, however, i see that it is very easy, i'm happy with the solution thank you